# Teamcity and msdeploy using powershell

Tags: powershell, msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy

I developed a powershell script that accepts a buncha parameters, creates an MSDeploy string, and executes it. I've tested this powershell command:

1. It works on my local box (installs the web app from my local box to
   a remote IIS server)
2. It works on the TeamCity box (installs the web
   app from team city's folder structure to remote iis server)

**problem:**

It doesn't work when I run the command from teamcity's browser version.

The error is: **ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN**

Please note, my Teamcity Build Agent is a local admin on both my teamcity server and IIS Remote server

**Powreshell Source Code:**

```
$msDeploy = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe'
$sourcePackage = $args[0]
$paramFile = $args[1]
$iisAppPath = $args[2]
$servername = $args[3]
$usreName = $args[4]
$password = $args[5]
$includeAcls = $args[6]

function UpdateParamFile($paramXMLFile, $applicationPath)
{
    $doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $doc.Load($paramXMLFile)

    #IIS Application Path (this is where the code will be deployed - it has to exist in target IIS):
    $appPath = $doc.SelectSingleNode("//parameters//setParameter[@name = 'IIS Web Application Name']")
    $appPath.value = $applicationPath

    #Connection Strings:

    #KDB Connection string:

    #Save
    $doc.Save($paramXMLFile)

    #[xml] $xmlPars = Get-Content $paramXMLFile
    #$xmlPars.parameters.setParameter | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'IIS Web Application Name' } | select value
}

UpdateParamFile $paramFile $iisAppPath
$arguments = "-source:package=$sourcePackage", "-dest:auto,computerName=`"$servername`",userName=`"$usreName`",password=`"$password`",includeAcls=`"$includeAcls`"", "-setParamFile:$paramFile", '-verb:sync', '-disableLink:AppPoolExtension', '-disableLink:CertificateExtension', '-disableLink:ContentExtension'
&$msDeploy $arguments
```

**Teamcity call to the above script file:**

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\253e6183c0596123\Debug\PMRSWebsite\DeployWeb.ps1 Debug\PMRSWebsite\Web.csproj.zip "Debug\PMRSWebsite\Web.csproj.SetParameters.xml" ^^^IIS_APP_NAME^^^ ^^^ServerName^^^ ^^^userName^^^ ^^^Password^^^ false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN

Diagnosis - This happens if you try to connect to the Remote Agent Service but 
  have not provided appropriate administrator credentials.

Resolution - The Remote Agent Service accepts either built-in Administrator or 
  Domain Administrator credentials. If you have a non-domain setup and want to 
  use account other that built-in administrator, please do following:

  1. Create a separate user group MSDepSvcUsers on remote computer.
  2. Create an local account A on both local & remote computer.
  3. Add A to MSDepSvcUsers on remote computer.
  4. Use account A to publish, this will allow you to publish without needing to 
     use built-in admin account.
```

[via](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes)

Comment: Nope, this won't do/is not the solution to the stated problem. The account I'm using is in fact a local admin on both boxes; as I mentioned earlier, I am able to run the msdeploy no problem; however, the exact same msdeploy code when executed from Teamcity gives the ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN error. Teamcity's build agent also runs under an account that is both local admin on both boxes and also in Domain Admin. To be clear, I run the msdeploy code from the TeamCity box which works in command line. It's the browser version of Teamcity that gives the error. I think the admin error is a red herring

Comment: Did you try the solution presented here?

Comment: Yes I did. About the "account", are we talking about the account that is specified in the -dest parameter for msdeploy, or are we talking about the account that is calling msdeploy (ie, teamcity build agent service account)? thanks for following up on this with me btw :)

Comment: Got it to work! the problem had to do with the way I generated the msdeploy script from TeamCity. In teamcity I parameterize the script to accept username, password, etc. and I was putting single quotes around the passed in values!!! hence it couldn't authenticate my user. I don't know if I'm happy, disappointed, ... anyways, definitely a plus 1 from me for your help! Cheers